# How to access private page (views page) with authentification in the URL?

Tags: tokens

All the pages of my site are private (by role). I have nodes and views pages.
I want to access to a views page with an external link. But, If the visitor isn't logged, this visitor can't access to the page.

Is there a solution to specify a token or the login / pass in the URL to automaticaly access to the page?

Comment: What makes it private if something in the URL makes it public?

Comment: I'm guessing the user meant private to anonymous users but not private to the holder of the tokenized link, like the one-time login link you get when resetting a password.

Comment: In an external tool (not Drupal), I need to access to a views page. But the datas are private. On this external tool, how to build the URL to access to my page with 1 automaticaly authentification system? WIth a specific token (saved token in the user account) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about these projects:

- [Auto Login URL](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_login_url)
- [Auto Login URL Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_login_url_tokens)
- [Token authentication](https://www.drupal.org/project/tokenauth)
- [Login one time](https://www.drupal.org/project/login_one_time)
- [One-time login](https://www.drupal.org/project/one_time_login)
- [urllogin](https://www.drupal.org/project/urllogin)

They're not all usable but you can get inspired by their different features and how they implement them so you can solve it for your own problem.